# getting the value from textarea into a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div -

```
<div id="chatText" class="chatText">Welcome</div>
```

and a textarea and button

```
New Message<br />
<textarea id="newChatText1" rows="3" cols="50" class="chatinput"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="AddContent()">
```

I want the user to be able to put content into the textarea and it get displayed and ADDED to the existing div content

So if the user entered 'Hello' into the textarea and pressed submit the div would display

'Welcome
Hello'

Current js is

```
function AddContent(){
    var text1 = $("#chatText").val();           
    var text2 = $("#newChatText1").val();   
    $("#chatText").text(text1+text2);   
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A div does not have a value

```
var text1 = $("#chatText").val();
```

needs to be text()

```
var text1 = $("#chatText").text();
```

For the new line, I would do this instead.

```
function AddContent(){
    var text2 = $("#newChatText1").val();   
    var p = $("<p></p>").text(text2);
    $("#chatText").append(p);   
}
```

Comment: excellent that's sorted that bit out. No how would I get the entries to appear on different lines.

Putting 

    $("#chatText").text(text1 + '<br/>' + text2);

just outputs the <br/> as is....

Paul

Comment: See my suggestion for new line.

Comment: how do I do that in my instance - $("#chatText").text(text1+text2);

Comment: $("#chatText").html(text1 + "<br />" + text2); works !

Comment: The issue with using `html()` is XSS injection. Yeah it will only affect the current user, but I always stick to safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .append() method to do that.

```
function addContent(){
    $("#chatText").append( $("#newChatText1").val() );
}
```